# python: open file, feed line to list, process list data

Tags: python, cairo, cairoplot

I want to process the data in the file "output.log" and feed it to graphdata['eth0]

I have done this but it process only the first line:

```
logread = open("output.log", "r").readlines()
for line in logread:
        print "line", line
        i = line.rstrip("\n")
        b = float(i)
        colors = [ (0.2, 03, .65), (0.5, 0.7, .1), (.35, .2, .45), ]
        graphData = {}
        graphData['eth0'] = [b]
        cairoplot.dot_line_plot("./blog", graphData, 500, 500, axis=True, grid=True, dots=True, series_colors=colors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
graphData = {}
```

I believe that is a dictionary.  Is that what you intended?

If you're looking for a list/array you can use [] instead of {}.  What a previous poster said sounds correct.  Every time through you are setting graphData = {} and therefore overwriting anything from the past.

```
array.append(x)
```

will append something to an array.

If you want all lines displayed all happily at the end you could set 
    graphData = [] 
before the loop.  Then each time through the loop do the

```
graphData.append(line).
```

Then after the loop you can set 
    graph_data_dict = {}
    graph_data_dict['eth0'] = graph_data_array

Answer (score 0):

```
logread = open("output.log", "r").readlines()
for line in logread:
        print "line", line
        i = line.rstrip("\n")
        b = float(i)
        colors = [ (0.2, 03, .65), (0.5, 0.7, .1), (.35, .2, .45), ]
        graphData = {}
        graphData['eth0'] = [b]
        cairoplot.dot_line_plot("./blog", graphData, 500, 500, axis=True, grid=True, dots=True, series_colors=colors)
```

Comment: Was there a difference there?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, bit it looks like you're re-initing the array each time.  Can you feed it in one big list?